# How to build library with debug symbols with homebrew?

Tags: macos, debugging, homebrew

Does `homebrew` have any option to build package with debug symbols? I develop an app with QT library and would like to have fast access to its source code from my IDE.

My steps of QT installing:

```
brew install qt
brew link --force qt
QT_V=`brew info --json=v1 qt | jsawk -n 'out(this.installed[0].version)'` \
  ln -sf /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/${QT_V}/mkspecs /usr/local/mkspecs && \
  ln -sf /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/${QT_V}/plugins /usr/local/plugins
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew doesn’t have such universal option. Run `brew info <formula>` to get which options are available for a given formula.

In the case of `qt` there’s no `--debug` option:

```
$ brew info qt
...
==> Options
--with-docs
    Build documentation
--with-examples
    Build examples
--with-mysql
    Build with mysql support
--with-postgresql
    Build with postgresql support
--with-qtwebkit
    Build with QtWebkit module
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

---

Side note: use `brew --prefix <formula>` to get a formula’s installed prefix. You’ll get a version-independent prefix if it’s linked:

```
$ brew --prefix qt
/home/baptiste/.linuxbrew/opt/qt
```

This works across formula upgrades because Homebrew takes care of updating the symlink.